# h:commandButton remains disabled even after changing disabled to true and re-rendering it using a4j:commandButton

Tags: jsf, commandbutton, disabled-control

I have a page with an `inputtext`where I type the name of an author to search for, when I click the `a4j:commandButton` `searchButton`, I'd like to enable the `h:commandButton` `GoToBUtton`, if the search returns no authors and to disabled that button, if the search returns an author. At first, the `GoToButton` should be disabled, that's the default behaviour.

The problem is, `goToButton` is always disabled, it never changes. What's wrong?

```
<h:form>
 <div align="left">
<rich:panel id="panel" style="width:310px">
           <h:panelGrid columns="3">
              Nome do autor: <h:inputText id="nameInput" 
              value="#{insertAuthControllerPt1.nameToSearch}"/>

                <a4j:commandButton id="searchButton" value="Procurar" 
           action="#{insertAuthControllerPt1.searchAuthor()}"
            render="authorTable, goToButton">              
           </a4j:commandButton>

           </h:panelGrid>  
       </rich:panel> 


   <h:panelGrid id="authorTable">
       <rich:dataTable value="#{insertAuthControllerPt1.authorListOfMap}"  var="result">
            <c:forEach items="#{insertAuthControllerPt1.variableNames}" var="vname">
                 <rich:column>
                     <f:facet name="header">#{vname}</f:facet>
                      #{result[vname]}
                 </rich:column> 
            </c:forEach>    
       </rich:dataTable>
       <br /> 
   </h:panelGrid>


<h:commandButton id="goToButton" value="Go" action="InsertAuthorPt2" 
           disabled="#{insertAuthControllerPt1.disabled}">
             <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{insertAuthorController.flag}"
                         value="true" />      
           </h:commandButton>
 </div>
</h:form>
```

**Search Method at InsertAuthControllerPt1.java**

```
public class InsertAuthorControllerPt1 {
    private boolean disabled;
    private String nameToSearch;
    private List<String> variableNames;
    private List<Map<String, String>> authorListOfMap;
    private String flag;
    private Map<String, Object> sessionMap;
    private List<Author> authors; 

    public InsertAuthorControllerPt1() {
        this.authorListOfMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        this.variableNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.sessionMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        this.authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
        this.disabled = true;
    }

    public void searchAuthor() {

            this.variableNames.clear();
            this.authorListOfMap.clear();

           if( this.nameToSearch.equals("") ) {
                this.disabled = true;
           } else {

             try {
                this.findAuthorByNameOperation(this.sessionMap, this.flag, this.nameToSearch);
            }catch(NullPointerException n) {

                this.disabled = false;

                }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

                if( (authors != null) && (!authors.isEmpty()) ) {

                    this.disabled = true;

                    for( Author author : authors ) {
                        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put("URI", author.getUri().toString());
                        map.put("Nome", author.getName());
                        map.put("Email", author.getEmail());
                        this.authorListOfMap.add(map);  
                    }
              this.addVariableNames();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First it is highly discouraged to mix JSTL tags and Facelets tags (see: [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets… makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3343681/696299))

Then you will use the [`f:ajax`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) tag. You will basically use an ajax call to render the `goToButton` after the action has been executed

```
<h:commandButton id="searchButton" value="Search" action="#{insertAuthControllerPt1.searchAuthor()}">
    <f:ajax render="goToButton">
</h:commandButton>
```

NOT to miss about using AJAX with JSF:

- Java tutorial : [Sending an Ajax Request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-ajax004.htm#GKHVT)
- [Max Katz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297847/max-katz) : [Learning JSF2: Ajax in JSF – using `f:ajax` tag](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/)
- [Lincoln Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202007/lincoln) : [render components outside of the form](http://ocpsoft.org/java/jsf2-java/how-to-jsf-2-0-render-components-outside-of-the-form/)

Comment: When I use your solution, I get a NullPointerException. I made some changes in my code according to what @Vasil suggestted me and I don't get a NullPointerException but the `goToButton` remains always disabled, even if I change the property disabled to true. I wrote the changes I made and changed the question above..

Comment: NullPointerException on what ? Possibly your problem is caused by using `c:forEach` (See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3343681/696299) the constructor is getting called multiple times which causes the `disabled` attribute to be always set to true. Otherwise, does your `authorTable` render well ?

Answer (score 0):

change `h:commandButton` to `a4j:commandButton` and add `render` attribute:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="searchButton" value="Search" 
    action="#{insertAuthControllerPt1.searchAuthor()}"
    render="goToButton" />
```

Comment: I used your solution and added the table that shows the search results at `render`. But the `goToButton` still remains always disabled. I wrote those changes in my code and changed the question above..

Comment: After update question I propose to check your Java code and if it correct try wrap goToButton with `a4:region`.